# How to properly forward a ref to a material-ui component from a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-forwardref

I'm using the following packages to create an autocomplete solution for an application I'm working on:

- [Material UI 4](https://material-ui.com/api/textarea-autosize/)
- [react-autocomplete-input](https://github.com/yury-dymov/react-autocomplete-input/blob/master/src/AutoCompleteTextField.js)

I'm trying to use the `Component` prop on the react-autocomplete-input element by passing in the material-ui `TextareaAutosize` component.

**Directly passing in TextareaAutosize from MUI**

```
import {TextareaAutosize} from '@material-ui/core';
<AutocompleteInput Component={TextareaAutosize} />
```

This works, however I don't have any control over the props it gets.

**Through a custom component so I can add props**

```
const CustomTextarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  // If I don't forward the ref I get an error...
  <TextareaAutosize
    placeholder="Material-ui through custom component..."
    ref={ref}
  />
));

<AutocompleteInput Component={CustomTextarea} />
```

This stops the autocomplete from working altogether.  However, the placeholder still shows properly which means the props are at least making it through.

You can see all the examples in my sandbox below.

**Examples:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wildflower-48iyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed to pass the default **props**

```js
const CustomTextarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  // If I don't forward the ref I get an error...
  <TextareaAutosize
    placeholder="Material-ui through custom component..."
    {...props} // here
    ref={ref}
  />
))
```

Comment: Can you also add an example on how to use this in App.js or any other component to pass the ref?